# Add line feed every 2391 byte

Tags: linux, unix

I am using Redhat Linux 6.

I have a file which should comes from mainframe MVS with EBCDIC-ASCII conversion.
(But I suspect some conversion may be wrong)

Anyway, I know that the record length is 2391 byte.  There are 10 records and the file size is 23910 byte.

For each 2391 byte record, there are many 0a or 0d char (not CRLF).  I want to replace them with, say, # and @.

Also, I want to add a LF (i.e.0a) every 2391 byte so as to make the file become a normal unix text file for further processing.

I have try to use

dd ibs=2391 obs=2391 if=emyfile of=myfile.new

But, this cannot work.  Both files are the same.

I also try

dd ibs=2391 obs=2391 if=myfile | awk '{print $0}'

But, this also not work

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
$ dd bs=2391 cbs=2391 conv=ascii,unblock if=emyfile of=myfile.new
```

`conv=ascii` converts from EBCDIC to ASCII. `conv=unblock` inserts a newline at the end of each `cbs`-sized block (after removing trailing spaces).

If you already have a file in ASCII and just want to replace some characters in it before splitting the blocks, you could use `tr(1)`. For example, the following will replace each carriage return with '#' and each newline (linefeed) with '@':

```
$ tr '\r\n' '#@' < emyfile | dd bs=2391 cbs=2391 conv=unblock of=myfile.new
```

Comment: Thanks Ulfalizer. I use [[ tr '\r\n' '#@' < emyfile | dd bs=2391 cbs=2391 conv=unblock of=myfile.new ]]  Then, when grep -in ^ myfile.new, the number of lines matches my expectation.  The beginning of each line seems correct.  The only shortcoming is that the trailing space is removed (seems to be) because the file size is much small.  Can I preserve all the trailing space ?  Because, for this kind of mainframe converted files, the fields are delimited by column position.  I have to cut -n2370-2379 to get the last 10-char field.

Comment: @AlvinSIU: I'm not aware of any ways to suppress the remove-trailing-spaces behavior with `unblock`. I think Mark's solution should work. His `echo` command adds the newline after each block (since `echo` outputs a newline by default unless you pass `-n`).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..9}; do
   dd if=emyfile bs=2391 count=1 skip=$i | LC_CTYPE=C tr '\r\n' '##'
   echo
done > newfile
```

If your files are longer, you will need more than 10 iterations. I would look to handle that by running an infinite looop and exiting the loop on error, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while :; do
   dd if=emyfile bs=2391 count=1 skip=$i | LC_CTYPE=C tr '\r\n' '##'
   [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ] && break
   echo
   ((i++))
done > newfile
```

However, on my iMac under OSX, `dd` doesn't seem to exit with an error when you go past end of file - maybe try your luck on your OS.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  This solution works.  Each record is 2391 byte + 1 byfe for 0a. This is what I expected.  However, the UAT file size is about 600 records.  The production size is much larger.  I need to do some calculation using  file size and record length in the [[ for i ]] statement.  I am lazy for this calculation.